# How to take a text file and create a copy but with numbered lines

Tags: python

This poem is saved in a text file:

```
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
   Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogroves,
   And the mom raths outgrabe.
               - Lewis Carroll
```

I want to create a copy of that file and change the name and have the output look like this:

```
1: 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
2:   Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
3: All mimsy were the borogroves,
4:   And the mom raths outgrabe.
5:             - Lewis Carroll
```

Can this be done using a loop or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Well i couldnt get it to work even with a loop so im open to any suggestions.

Comment: Are there any existing newlines or is it one continuous string?

Comment: Does it have to be python? AWK can do it really easily: `awk '{ print FNR, $0 }' < your_file.txt`

Comment: ahh sorry, didnt realize it looked like that. Theyre separate lines, not a continuous string. So basically I want it to look how it does now, without the spaces between lines

Comment: Please show the code that didn't work so we can actually show you what went wrong. Hint: there's nothing wrong with a loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can iterate through each line of the poem file and get the line number using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
with open('poem.txt') as poem_file:
    with open('poem-numbered.txt', 'w') as numbered_file:
        for index, line in enumerate(poem_file, 1):
            numbered_file.write('{}: {}'.format(index, line))
```

The code above first opens the original poem file (`poem.txt`) and then opens a file for writing to it (hence the `w` as the second argument to `open`). It then iterates through the lines of the original file and writes the line to the output file (`poem-numbered.txt`) with the line number.

When passing `w` as the second argument to [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), if the file already exists, it will be overwritten and if it doesn't exist, it will be created.